# Do you know or did you know?

Tags: british-english

> - **Do** you even know how bad that show was
> - **Did** you even know how bad that show was?

Which sentence is the correct one ?

If both are correct, can you give me some contexts for these to be applicable.
 Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why you have included the word **even** in these sentences. what meaning are you trying to convey? Based on your research, what is the difference between **do** and **did**? Please update your question to add these details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Did you know?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120359/did-you-know)

Answer (score 1):

**Version 1** (Do) is *correct* in the context: *If you don't know (unlikely you can imagine), I'll tell you **how** it was bad.*

A version with '**Did you know...**' usually means that the question reveals some fact to the other person who possibly did not know about it just a moment before 
(http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/When-to-Use-Did-You-Know-Instead-of-Do-You-Know-), e. g. in a modification:

> *Did you* (even) *know* **that show was really bad**? 
> [like, now you know it
>   from my question, but did you know it before I mentioned that fact by putting this question?]

**Version 2** from the question (**did** instead of **do**) sounds less natural, since '*even*' expresses a strong doubt (about imagining '*how bad*' by the other person) and eagerness of the speaker to explain further '**how**' the show was *bad*.

Answer (score 0):

I think both of these sentences are right!

Below examples from literature for you:

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6341655-tears-of-pearl
**Did you even know I was here?**

> She laughed. 
>     “Do you think, Emily, that I do not already know everything you do? 
>     You are to be set upon us, asking questions. 
>     That is not why I have summoned you here.”
>
> “Then why?”
>
> “I have decided to offer you my allegiance. 
>     My support. 
>     Without which you will flail and accomplish nothing. 
>     **Did you even know I was here?**
>     That this graveyard for the previous sultans’ women existed?”
>
> “No. 
>     I confess I did not.”

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14060046-obsession
**“Did you even know where to go when you hit the road?**

> “You shouldn’t just expect people to obey your demands,” she said, trying and failing to shrug off my hands.
>
> A muscle started to spasm in my jaw. 
>     **“Did you even know where to go when you hit the road?** 
>     Well, let me tell you. 
>     If you take a right, it would have led you into town.
>
> But it’s about thirty miles and it’s not a straight shot, either. 
>     There are mountain lions around here, even a few wolves. 
>     Not to mention the bears. 
>     And a few human males you probably wouldn’t want to meet in a dark alley. 
>     You know where taking a left brings you. 
>     This is a neighborhood of sorts, a very exclusive one, if you get what I’m saying. 
>     Others of my kind are here and they like to play with humans—and there were three of them focused on you.”

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/944076.Last_Argument_of_Kings
**“Do you even know how?”**

> “Your August Majesty,” said Ardee with the very heaviest of irony. 
>     “What a towering honour. 
>     Should I grovel on my face? 
>     Or do I curtsey?”
>
> However hard her words, the sound of her voice still made the breath catch in his throat. 
>     “Curtsey?” he managed to say. 
>     **“Do you even know how?”**
>
> “In truth, not really. 
>     I have not had the training for polite society, and now the lack of it quite crushes me.” 
>     She stepped forward, frowning into the darkened garden. 
>     “When I was a girl, in my wildest flights of fancy, I used to dream of being invited to the palace, a guest of the king himself. 
>     We would eat fine cakes, and drink fine wine, and talk fine talk of important things, deep into the night.” 
>     Ardee pressed her hands to her chest and fluttered her eyelashes. 
>     “Thank you for making the pitiful dreams of one poor wretch come true, if only for the briefest moment. 
>     The other beggars will never believe me when I tell them!”

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10834868-the-spirit-war
**Do you even know how… how…”**

> “Doesn’t matter,” she said quietly. 
>     “I’m here now.”
>
> “Doesn’t matter?” 
>     Josef was surprised at his own anger. 
>     “Doesn’t matter? 
>     Of course it matters! 
>       **Do you even know how… how…”**
>
> “Worried?” 
>     Eli supplied.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12081652-unchained
**“Do you even know how many favors I had to call in?**

> Lily shifted, the leather creaking under her slight weight. 
>     “I know.”
>
> **“Do you even know how many favors I had to call in?** 
>     Danyal put his neck on the line so no one would question why that young man didn’t come off his shift.”
>
> She fidgeted in the seat. 
>     Danyal had enmeshed himself deep within the police department just in case they needed someone in times like these. 
>     But favors were always few and hard to cover up.